# Can't connect to MySQL server (10060) and (4)

Tags: mysql, realbasic

I'm trying to make an application in RealBasic. I'm failing to create a connection with the remote server.

On XP (VirtualMachine):

> Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx' (10060)

On the latest OS X:

> Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx' (4)

However:
HeidiSQL & Sequel Pro connect fine. Another self-made app in .NET connects fine. Yet everything seems to be firewall related if I Google.

The code, if it helps:

```
dim db as new MySQLCommunityServer
db.host = ""
db.port = 3306
db.databasename = "dbname"
db.username = "dbuser"
db.password = "dbpass"
if (db.connect = true) then MsgBox("Connected") else MsgBox(db.errormessage)
```

Comment: Are you using SSL? Have you tried db.ConnectSSL instead?

Comment: Check that your mysql server is set to allow TCP connections. Most default installs do not, and work with local unix-domain sockets only.

Comment: why the host is an empty string?

Comment: Its just empty because it's an example. The problem is solved though - it had nothing to do with the app but with the mysql server just like Marc B suggested.